# Filter rows based on two criteria

Tags: r, dataframe

My dataframe looks like this:

```
Key   Year    Type
A     2000    ok
A     2001    ok
A     2001    notok
A     2002    ok
A     2003    ok
B     2000    ok
B     2001    ok
B     2001    ok
B     2002    ok
B     2003    ok
C     2000    ok
C     2001    ok
C     2002    ok
C     2003    ok
```

I am looking for a code that gives me back all of the Letters in my column key if there are two observations in a certain year with one of them saying "notok" and the other "ok" in my column type.
I do not want to have in my new dataframe the key b even though there are 2 observations in one year. It is because in my column Type the observations are both marked with ok.

So the answer should look like this:

```
Key   Year    Type
A     2000    ok
A     2001    ok
A     2001    notok
A     2002    ok
A     2003    ok
```

Is there a simple code for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this also takes into account the 'Year' column, then we have to group by 'Key' and 'Year'

```
df1 %>%
   group_by(Key, Year) %>% 
   mutate(n = sum(c("ok", "notok") %in% Type)) %>% 
   group_by(Key) %>% 
   filter(any(n == 2)) %>%
   select(-n)
# A tibble: 5 x 3
# Groups:   Key [1]
#  Key    Year Type 
#  <chr> <int> <chr>
#1 A      2000 ok   
#2 A      2001 ok   
#3 A      2001 notok
#4 A      2002 ok   
#5 A      2003 ok
```

---

Or using `base R` `ave`

```
i1 <- with(df1, ave(ave(Type, Key, Year, FUN = 
        function(x) length(unique(x)))==2, Key, FUN = any))
df1[i1,]
# Key Year  Type
#1   A 2000    ok
#2   A 2001    ok
#3   A 2001 notok
#4   A 2002    ok
#5   A 2003    ok
```

Or using `split` with `table`

```
subset(df1, Key %in% names(which(sapply(split(df1[-1], Key), 
     function(x) ncol(table(x))==2))))
```

---

Based on the expected output, after grouping by 'Key', `filter` those 'Key's having both "ok" and "notok" `%in%` the 'Type' column

```
df1 %>%
  group_by(Key) %>% 
  filter(all(c("ok", "notok") %in% Type))
# A tibble: 5 x 3
# Groups:   Key [1]
#  Key    Year Type 
#  <chr> <int> <chr>
#1 A      2000 ok   
#2 A      2001 ok   
#3 A      2001 notok
#4 A      2002 ok   
#5 A      2003 ok
```

If there are only 'ok' and 'notok' in the 'Type', we can count the number of unique elements to `filter`

```
df1 %>% 
   group_by(Key) %>%
   filter(n_distinct(Type)==2)
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(Key = c("A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", 
"B", "B", "C", "C", "C", "C"), Year = c(2000L, 2001L, 2001L, 
2002L, 2003L, 2000L, 2001L, 2001L, 2002L, 2003L, 2000L, 2001L, 
2002L, 2003L), Type = c("ok", "ok", "notok", "ok", "ok", "ok", 
"ok", "ok", "ok", "ok", "ok", "ok", "ok", "ok")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-14L))
```

Comment: @bli12blu12  Sure, you can do `df1 %>% group_by(Key, Year) %>% mutate(n= n() ) %>% group_by(Key) %>% filter(any(n == 2)) %>% select(-n)`

Answer (score 3):

Using `data.table`:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)

# option 1
df[Key %in% df[, .SD[uniqueN(Type) == 2], by = .(Key, Year)][, unique(Key)] ]

# option 2
df[, .SD[any(.SD[, uniqueN(Type), by = Year]$V1 == 2)], by = Key]

# option 3
df[, if (any(.SD[, uniqueN(Type), by = Year]$V1 == 2)) .SD, by = Key]
```

which gives:

> ```
>    Key Year  Type
> 1:   A 2000    ok
> 2:   A 2001    ok
> 3:   A 2001 notok
> 4:   A 2002    ok
> 5:   A 2003    ok
> ```

---

The same logic applied with `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)
k <- df %>% 
  group_by(Key, Year) %>% 
  filter(n_distinct(Type) == 2) %>% 
  distinct(Key) %>% 
  pull(Key)

df %>% filter(Key %in% k )
```

---

Or with base R:

```
k <- unique(df$Key[with(df, ave(Type, Key, Year, FUN = function(x) length(unique(x)))) == 2])
df[df$Key %in% k, ]
```